# Inverse scaling equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to scale two values which are not linear. I have (0,4095), which should be scaled between (20,0). The minimum of one set equals the maximum of the other set. What equation does this?

Comment: Do you have other data and examples of what you want the scaling to be? Regards

Comment: Well...0 should correspond to 20 and 4095 to 0. Did that answer your question?

Comment: That is not enough of a data set to make a determination. Will there be other sets of different numbers that could change the result of this single sample?

Comment: Are you still here, Brindhaa? Any thoughts on the comments, or on my answer?

Comment: Amzoti, I'm reading values from an Analog card which sends me values from 0-4095. I have to display them in the range of 20-0. I got the equation and it works very well. I believe I was not clear in my previous post. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "values which are not linear".

The function $(20/4095)(4095-v)$ takes the value $v=0$ to $20$, and the value $v=4095$ to $0$, as desired (but it is a linear function, so maybe it's not what you want).

If you will be a little more forthcoming on your desiderata, it might be possible to cook up a scaling which will be to your liking.

Comment: Thank you Gerry. I came up with the same too. The equation works very well. What I meant with "not linear" is that, the minimum of one set does not map to the minimum of  the other set. Sorry for the confusion! and thank you for your time. Appreciate it.