# Inverse scaling in which the range [-2.5, 2.5] becomes [3, 1]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to figure out how to inverse scale a range of -2.5 to 2.5 to the range of 3 to 1. -2.5 should turn to 3 and 2.5 should turn to 1. I have tried [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463964/inverse-scaling-equation), but the solution is not suitable when I insert negative values (-2.5 goes to 6). However, even if I shift the initial range to non-negative values (make [-2.5, 2.5] into [0, 5]), the maximum value gets turned into 0 instead of needed 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You composed two of the three maps necessary to solve the problem.
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = x + 2.5\\
g(x) & = \frac{2}{5}(5 - x)\\
\end{align*}
When you applied $f$ to $[-2.5, 2.5]$, it was mapped onto $[0, 5]$.  When you applied $g$ to $[0, 5]$, it mapped onto $[0, 2]$, with inverse scaling.  That is, 
$$(g \circ f)(x) = \frac{2}{5}[5 - (x + 2.5)] = \frac{2}{5}(2.5 - x)$$
maps $[-2.5, 2.5]$ onto $[0, 2]$ with inverse scaling.  To complete the problem, you need to add $1$ to each element in the interval $[0, 2]$, which can be done with the composition $(h \circ g \circ f)(x)$, where $h(x) = x + 1$.

Comment: Much more rigorous and elegant approach in comparison to what I managed to come up with after sleeping on the problem for a couple of minutes. I LOVE IT.